# How to detect contiguous spans in which data changes linearly within a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, ransac

I'm trying to detect contiguous spans in which the relevant variable changes linearly within certain data in a DataFrame. There may be many spans within the data that satisfy this. I started my aproach using `ransac` based on [Robust linear model estimation using RANSAC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ransac.html). However I'm having issues using the example for my data.

### Objective

Detect contiguous spans in which the relevant variable changes linearly within data. The spans to be detected are composed by more than 20 consecutive data points. The desired output would be the range dates in which the contiguous spans are placed.

### Toy example

In the toy exmple code below I generate random data and then set two portions of the data to create a contiguous spans that vary linearly. Then I try to fit a linear regression model to the data. The rest of the code I used (which is not shown here) is just the rest of the code in the [Robust linear model estimation using RANSAC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ransac.html) page. However I know I would need to change that remaining code in order to reach the goal.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets
import numpy as np

## 1. Generate random data for toy sample
times = pd.date_range('2016-08-10', periods=100, freq='15min')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), index=times, columns=["data"])

## 2. Set line1 within random data
date_range1_start = "2016-08-10 08:15"
date_range1_end = "2016-08-10 15:00"
line1 = df.data[date_range1_start:date_range1_end]
value_start1 = 10
values1 = range(value_start1,value_start1+len(line1))
df.data[date_range1_start:date_range1_end] = values1

## 3. Set line2 within random data
date_range2_start = "2016-08-10 17:00"
date_range2_end = "2016-08-10 22:30"
value_start2 = 90
line2 = df.data[date_range2_start:date_range2_end]
values2 = range(value_start2,value_start2-len(line2),-1)
df.data[date_range2_start:date_range2_end] = values2

## 4. Plot data
df.plot()
plt.show()

## 5. Create arrays
X = np.asarray(df.index)
y = np.asarray(df.data.tolist())

## 6. Fit line using all data
lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)
```

For this toy example code a desired output (which I wasn't able to code yet) would be a DataFrame like this:

```
>>> out
              start               end
0  2016-08-10 08:15  2016-08-10 15:00
1  2016-08-10 17:00  2016-08-10 22:30
```

The graph generated looks like:
[image: Data generated]

### Error code

However when step 6 is executed I get below error:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: ... Reshape your
>   data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single
>   feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

I would like to be able to detect in this example both contiguous spans in which the relevant variable changes linearly (`line1` and `line2`). But I'm not being able to implement the example stated on the [ransac code example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ransac.html).

### Question

**What should I modify** in my code to be able to continue? And, **may there be a better approach to achieve to detect the contiguous spans in which the relevant variable changes linearly**?

Comment: We need sample data

Comment: I created sample data in the toy example. I may provide real data but not sure how I can do that. I have some data in a pickle file.

Comment: Sorry. Then I don't get what you call a graph. To my mind, a graph is a set of nodes and edges.

Comment: By "linear graphs within the data," I believe @CedricZoppolo means "contiguous spans in which the relevant variable changes linearly." He means graph as in plot, not graph as in nodes and edges.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler is correct. I may have used the wrong term. I will try to rephrase my question to ensure everyone understands my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just go on and fit your linear regression, you will have to do the following:

```
lr.fit(X.reshape(-1,1), y)
```

It is because `sklearn` is waiting for a 2d array of values, with each row being a row of features.

So after this would you like to fit models for many different ranges and see if you find spans of linear change?

If you are looking for exactly linear ranges (which is possible to detect in the case of integers for example, but not for floats), then I would do something like:

```
dff = df.diff()
dff['block'] = (dff.data.shift(1) != dff.data).astype(int).cumsum()
out = pd.DataFrame(list(dff.reset_index().groupby('block')['index'].apply(lambda x: \
    [x.min(), x.max()] if len(x) > 20 else None).dropna()))
```

Output would be:

```
>>> out
                    0                   1
0 2016-08-10 08:30:00 2016-08-10 15:00:00
1 2016-08-10 17:15:00 2016-08-10 22:30:00
```

If you are trying to do something similar, but for float data, I would do something using `diff` the same way, but then specifying some kind of acceptable error or similar. Please let me know if this is what you would like to achieve. Or here you could also use RANSAC for sure on different ranges (but that would just discard the terms which are not well aligned, so if there would be some element breaking the span, you would still detect it as being a span). Everything depends on what are you exactly interested in.

Comment: I used `(abs(dff.data.shift(1)-dff.data) >= 1e-6)` instead of `(dff.data.shift(1) != dff.data)` as I was working with floats

Answer (score 5):

## ValueError

To answer the question about the ValueError: The reason you are getting the error and the example isn't, is that while you originally create an array with shape `(100,1)` (like the example), the linear model is fitting to `df.data.tolist()` which has a shape `(100,)`.  This can be fixed by reshaping `X` to 2D by `X = X.reshape(-1,1)`.  The next error will be that the `X` values cannot be in `datetime64` format.  This could then be fixed by converting the time to seconds.  For example, a standard epoch to use is `1970-01-01T00:00Z` and then all data points are seconds since that date and time.  This conversion can be done by:

```
X = (X - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

Here's the full code showing the linear fit in the plot below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets
import numpy as np

## 1. Generate random data for toy sample
times = pd.date_range('2016-08-10', periods=100, freq='15min')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), index=times, columns=["data"])

## 2. Set line1 within random data
date_range1_start = "2016-08-10 08:15"
date_range1_end = "2016-08-10 15:00"
line1 = df.data[date_range1_start:date_range1_end]
value_start1 = 10
values1 = range(value_start1,value_start1+len(line1))
df.data[date_range1_start:date_range1_end] = values1

## 3. Set line2 within random data
date_range2_start = "2016-08-10 17:00"
date_range2_end = "2016-08-10 22:30"
value_start2 = 90
line2 = df.data[date_range2_start:date_range2_end]
values2 = range(value_start2,value_start2-len(line2),-1)
df.data[date_range2_start:date_range2_end] = values2


## 4. Create arrays
X = np.asarray(df.index)
X = ( X - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
X = X.reshape(-1,1)
y = np.asarray(df.data.tolist())

## 5. Fit line using all data
lr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)

## 6. Predict values
z = lr.predict(X)
df['linear fit'] = z

## 7. Plot
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

## Detecting Contiguous Spans

To detect the spans of linear data, as you stated, RANSAC is a good method to use.  To do this, the linear model would be changed to `lr = linear_model.RANSACRegressor()`.  However, this would only return one span, whereas you need to detect all spans.  This means you need to repeat the span detections, while removing the spans after each detection so they don't get detected again.  This should be repeated until the number of points in a detected span is less than 20.

The residual threshold for the RANSAC fit needs to be very small so as not to pick up points outside the span.  The `residual_threshold` can be changed if there is any noise in the real data.  However, this is not always going to be sufficient, and false inliers are likely to be found, which will affect the recorded span ranges.

#### False Inliers

Since RANSAC is not checking if the in-span points are consecutive, it is possible for outliers to be falsely included in a span.  To guard against this, points marked as in-span should be changed to outliers if they are surrounded by outliers.  The fastest way to do this is to convolve `lr.inlier_mask_` with `[1,1,1]`.  Any solitary "inliers" will have a value of 1 after the convolution (and are thus really outliers), while points as part of a span run will be 2 or 3.  Thus, the following will fix false inliers:

```
lr.inlier_mask_ = np.convolve(lr.inlier_mask_.astype(int), [1,1,1], mode='same') > 1
```

#### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets
import numpy as np

## 1. Generate random data for toy sample
times = pd.date_range('2016-08-10', periods=100, freq='15min')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), index=times, columns=["data"])

## 2. Set line1 within random data
date_range1_start = "2016-08-10 08:15"
date_range1_end = "2016-08-10 15:00"
line1 = df.data[date_range1_start:date_range1_end]
value_start1 = 10
values1 = range(value_start1,value_start1+len(line1))
df.data[date_range1_start:date_range1_end] = values1

## 3. Set line2 within random data
date_range2_start = "2016-08-10 17:00"
date_range2_end = "2016-08-10 22:30"
value_start2 = 90
line2 = df.data[date_range2_start:date_range2_end]
values2 = range(value_start2,value_start2-len(line2),-1)
df.data[date_range2_start:date_range2_end] = values2

## 4. Create arrays
X = np.asarray(df.index)
X = ( X - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
X = X.reshape(-1,1)
y = np.asarray(df.data.tolist())

## 5. Fit line using all data
lr = linear_model.RANSACRegressor(residual_threshold=0.001)
lr.fit(X, y)

# Placeholders for start/end times
start_times = []
end_times = []

# Repeat fit and check if number of span inliers is greater than 20
while np.sum(lr.inlier_mask_) > 20:

    # Remove false inliers
    lr.inlier_mask_ = np.convolve(lr.inlier_mask_.astype(int), [1,1,1], mode='same') > 1

    # Store start/end times
    in_span = np.squeeze(np.where(lr.inlier_mask_))
    start_times.append(str(times[in_span[0]]))
    end_times.append(str(times[in_span[-1]]))

    # Get outlier and check for another span
    outliers = np.logical_not(lr.inlier_mask_)
    X = X[outliers]
    y = y[outliers]
    times = times[outliers]

    # Fit to remaining points
    lr.fit(X, y)

out = pd.DataFrame({'start':start_times, 'end':end_times}, columns=['start','end'])
out.sort_values('start')
```

Here's the `out` dataframe:

[image]

You can also plot the spans to verify.

```
plt.plot(df['data'],c='b')

for idx,row in out.iterrows():
    x0 = np.datetime64(row['start'])
    y0 = df.loc[x0]['data']
    x1 = np.datetime64(row['end'])
    y1 = df.loc[x1]['data']
    plt.plot([x0,x1],[y0,y1],c='r')
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is greatly detailed and works as I expect. Hence I will set the bounty to this answer. However I will accept the other solution that uses a simple but effective method.